# React form doesn't send data to php file

Tags: php, reactjs

Last weeks I work on a React site. And everything went okay, but I would like to make a contact page with a form. In HTML/PHP you just use action="", but I tried that, but it is not working.

Can someone help me out?

**form-contact.js:**

```
    import React from 'react';

    const ContactForm = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className={'inputs'} style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            width: 46 + '%'
        }}>
            <form action={'../mail_functions/mailto.php'} method={'POST'} encType={'multipart/form-data'}>
                <div>
                    <span>Uw naam</span>
                </div>
                <input name={'username'} type={'text'} id={'name'} required/>

                <div>
                    <span>Uw emailadres</span>
                </div>
                <input name={'email-address'} type={'email'} id={'emailaddress'} required/>

                <div>
                    <span>Onderwerp</span>
                </div>
                <input name={'subject-mail'} type={'text'} id={"subject"} required/>

                <div>
                    <span>Uw bericht</span>
                </div>
                <textarea name={'contentmail'} id={'message'} style={{
                    maxWidth: 100 + '%',
                    minWidth: 100 + '%',
                    maxHeight: 200 + 'px',
                    minHeight: 40 + 'px'
                }} required/>

                <input type={"submit"} name={'submit'} value={'Verstuur'}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
    }

    export default ContactForm;
```

**mailto.php:**

```
    <?php

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $emailAddress = $_POST['email-address'];
    $subjectMail = $_POST['subject-mail'];
    $contentMail = $_POST['contentmail'];
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];

    $msg = 'testmail succesvol ontvangen!';
    $mailTo = 'info@lala.com';


    if(isset($submit) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        mail($mailTo, "testmail", $msg);

    }

    header('Location: ../pages/contact.js');
    die();
```

Hopefully someone could help me out. I am struggling with this for multiple days.

Answer (score 0):

your solution is here :

https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-build-a-contact-form-with-react-js-and-php-d5977c17fec0

Set all variable value in state json **(react)**
and fetch in php file like

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);
```

full description here : https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-build-a-contact-form-with-react-js-and-php-d5977c17fec0

Comment: Yea I know what you mean, but it looks like he don't reach my PHP file, what seems strange

Comment: @user12380607  If you created your react app already in Apache or Nginx www folder, you can go to your project root and create index.php file and put your php code